# How to get current routeName?

Tags: ember.js

Assuming my application in bound to `window.App`:
I can get it's router with `App.__container__.lookup("router:main")`.

How can I access current route? Specifically I want to get its property `routeName`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It exist a property called `currentPath` which is a computed alias for the current state of the application. To get the current `routeName` which is the same thing you could do something like this:

```
App = Ember,Application.create({
  currentPath: ''
});

ApplicationController : Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPathDidChange: function() {
    App.set('currentPath', this.get('currentPath'));
  }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

and then access it from anywhere with:

```
App.get('currentPath');
```

See [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.5/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L75) for more info for the `currentPath` property.

Also worth mentioning is that you can enable the flag `LOG_TRANSITIONS` to true to have the current route name logged in your browser console every time the application changes state/route:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITION: true
});
```

**Note**
Use this `App.__container__.lookup("router:main")` only for debugging purposes since it's an internal API.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using `App.__container__.lookup` to fix a bug in Ember core, and thus I cannot extend application controller. Where I can find `currentState` exactly? It is not a property of either `App` or `Router`.

Comment: the link if very helpful, thank you. but how to access `StateManager` from `App`?

Comment: The `StateManager` was used for the previous version of the router, now in *v2* the router does it's own work to route etc. The `currentPath` property on the `ApplicationController` is handled here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.5/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L75

Comment: I've edited the link in my answer, it was referring to the wrong place, sorry :)

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Unfortunately currentPath is not available when I need it but still it good to know where to look it up.