# Is there a way to find out from which route it was transitioned to the current route in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

Let's say we have 3 routes: A, B and C

There is a possibility to transition from A to C. Or from B to C.

```
A -> C
B -> C
```

In route C I would like to know from which route it was transitioned. Either A or B. Is there a easy way to find that?

P.S. What I'm thinking of doing is to add an extra parameter with the route name (A or B) when transitioning from A (or B) to C and get that parameter on the `beforeModel` hook of route C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [How to get current routeName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244353/how-to-get-current-routename)

I've added a `previousRoute` property. It is easier than using query parameters.

Solution:

```
 App = Ember,Application.create({
      currentPath: '',
      previousPath: null
 });

ApplicationController : Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPathDidChange: function() {
      App.set('previousPath', App.get('currentPath'));
      App.set('currentPath', this.get('currentPath'));
  }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

The properties can be accessed using:

```
App.get('currentPath');
App.get('previousPath');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the query parameters in the following ways:
[controller](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute) / [route](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo) And access them in the route

```
beforeModel:function(transition){
   transition.queryParams
}
```

So from a you set the query paramter to A and do what you need in beforeModel based on A. same for B

Comment: That's what I was thinking initially, but I come up with the solution described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Ember **v3.6**, a `from` property has been added to the `Transition` class.  This property is a `RouteInfo` object that represents where transition originated from. For a inital render, the value is set to `null`.

```
// routes/b.js

// transition from A --> B
beforeModel(model, transition) {
    console.log(transition.from); // A;
}
```

Link to docs: https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.6/classes/Transition/properties/from?anchor=from